# Exception in Application start method error. Other solutions not working

Tags: java, javafx

Everything was going well, then I run my code and I get this error.

I have already tried the following solutions (nothing worked):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000423/javafx-and-maven-nullpointerexception-location-is-required

[Exception in Application start method javafx gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806620/exception-in-application-start-method-javafx-gui)

[Exception in Application start method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137371/exception-in-application-start-method)

[JavaFX "Location is required." even though it is in the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package)

main.java

```
package stockBot;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="stockBot.Main">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass="background-bar" stylesheets="@application.css" />
      <Button maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="20.0" styleClass="background-button-exit" stylesheets="@application.css" translateX="1000.0" translateY="12.0">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="CLOSE" size="16" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <Button maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="20.0" styleClass="background-button-minus" stylesheets="@application.css" translateX="975.0" translateY="12.0">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="MINUS" size="16" translateY="2.0" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <Label text="Stock" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Avenir Heavy Oblique" size="43.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label text="Bot" textFill="#3fae2a" translateX="110.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Avenir Heavy Oblique" size="43.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="create-task-btn" stylesheets="@application.css" text="Create Task" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#ababab" translateX="450.0" translateY="10.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Avenir Heavy" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TableView prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="950.0" styleClass="table-main" stylesheets="@application.css" translateX="37.0" translateY="70.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="395.4969062805176" styleClass="table-item" text="Product Name" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="97.50311279296875" styleClass="table-item" text="Current Price" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="92.45794677734375" styleClass="table-item" text="Lowest Price" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="99.64276123046875" styleClass="table-item" text="Refresh Delay" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="137.58929443359375" styleClass="table-item" text="Account Email" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="123.0" styleClass="table-item" text="Tools" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

project.iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/resources" type="java-resource" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="lib" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Heres are my files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPcX8.png

Error Message

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at stockBot.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application stockBot.Main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include "resources" in the call to `getResources()`. Try replacing it with `getClass().getResource("/main.fxml")` and it should work (assuming no other errors). Note, the leading slash is important.

How your code is currently, the `FXMLLoader` is looking for a file at `src/main/resources/resources/main.fxml`, which is probably not where your file is. If you do indeed have 2 folders called `resources`, then you should use `getClass().getResource("/resources/main.fxml")` (again with the leading slash).