# Exception in Application start method. JavaFx 11

Tags: java, javafx

I try to create a screen with one TextField and Button and receve "Exception in Application start method". Firt time I try solution from this questions and dont work:

[Exception in Application start method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137371/exception-in-application-start-method)

[Exception in Application start method javafx gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806620/exception-in-application-start-method-javafx-gui)

[JavaFX "Location is required." even though it is in the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package)

[Exception in Application start method error. Other solutions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205854/exception-in-application-start-method-error-other-solutions-not-working)

I use Java 11, javaFx 11.
For javaFx I use maven.

The main class is :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StartClass extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception  {
        Parent parent =     FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../userInterface/CreateProjectScreen.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("IEPCP");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(parent ));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

The FXML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="controllers.ui.CreateProjectController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="402.0" prefWidth="601.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="sendButton" layoutX="249.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendButtonClicked" text="Button" />
            <TextField fx:id="directory" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="85.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="470.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CreateProjectController {

    @FXML
    private TextField directory;

    @FXML
    private Button sendButton;

    public TextField getDirectory() {
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(TextField directory) {
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    public void sendButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        System.out.println("You write: " + getDirectory().getText());
    }
}
```

This is error receved:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x3e122bd1) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x3e122bd1
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at primary.StartClass.start(StartClass.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application primary.StartClass
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your full pom, or at least the plugin you use to run the application. If you run from your IDE (which one?), post the VM arguments you use.

Comment: Assuming your own code is not modular (i.e. no `module-info.java` file) then you need to include `javafx.fxml` in the `--add-modules` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is to do with the path that you are providing to your `FXMLLoader`. 
If your FXML file is in `src/main/resources/userInterface/CreateProjectScreen.fxml`, then your `FXMLLoader` should be called as follows:

```
Parent parent =     FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/userInterface/CreateProjectScreen.fxml"));
```

The leading slash refers to the root of the classpath (i.e. `src/main/resources`). The path following that is the relative path to the FXML file.

You are also getting a module access error. You need to export the module listed in the error message, otherwise JavaFX will not be able to access it.

Comment: I try and don't work. This is project hierarchy : http://prntscr.com/okf9vo

Comment: The FXMLLoader should be called as in my answer. See Gweltaz Niquel's answer for more detail of how to fix the module access answer I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just moved my Main.java file into src/Main/java. And this worked for me